# Unable to install tensorflow-gpu on anaconda with PackagesNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, tensorflow2.0

I have created new environment in anaconda, webapp-env, to use streamlit and flask.

I have installed  cuda (8.1) and cudatoolkit (11.2) so it is compatible with my environment and am trying to install tensorflow-gpu=2.8.0 (or 2.9.0) as per the table here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows

Unfortunately, I am getting this error (below) and I dont know how to solve this.

```
(webapp-env) PS C:\Users\me\Coursera_NN_visualizer_web_app_MNIST_project> conda config --append channels conda-forge tensorflow-gpu = 2.9.0
usage: conda-script.py [-h] [-V] command ...
conda-script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: tensorflow-gpu = 2.9.0

(webapp-env) PS C:\Users\me\Coursera_NN_visualizer_web_app_MNIST_project> conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow-gpu=2.8.0
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - tensorflow-gpu=2.8.0

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I have an Nvidia 3060 graphics card and can use tensorflow-gpu version 2.8.0 successfully in my  anaconda base virtual environment.
any advice?

Answer (score 2):

In tensorflow 2.10 GPU support is included and tensorflow-gpu installs no longer work.

Answer (score 1):

Tnesorflow-GPU in the `main`channel is at version `2.6` and from `conda-forge`, only a linux version is available, see [here](https://anaconda.org/main/tensorflow-gpu) and [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow-gpu)

You probably used `pip` to install it in your base env. You can do so in your new env just as well

Comment: thank you! now it says  that tensorflow 2.6.0 needs the python version 3.7, 3.8 and 3.9. and I have upgraded my python to 3.10.    so not sure now if to downgrade my python to 3.9, or try pip to install tensorflow 2.8.0.

Comment: you should be able to do `conda install python=3.9`